# Guidence: HTML table format

Tags: html, html-table

I am working on a a html form which is used by a third party tool which takes HTML format to generate the output form.

Here is the html output:

[image]

This is the current output:
[image]

The issue which I am facing is when I trying to separate below marked table to a new table I am loosing the format. Can anyone please guide me how to maintain the same format when I remove the below mentioned table to a new table.

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border: solid;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" style="width: 289.333px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">section 1</span></td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="width: 70px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">section 2</span></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="width: 289.333px; border: solid; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">section 3</span></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="width: 7px; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">4</span></span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="7" style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">(4)<br>&nbsp;DAY AND DATE</span></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="width: 70px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">(5)<br>&nbsp;section</span></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="width: 150px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">(6)<br>&nbsp;section</span></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4" style="width: 150px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">(7)<br>&nbsp;section</span></span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="4" rowspan="3" style="text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">(8)<br>&nbsp;DEDUCTIONS</span></span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" rowspan="4" style="text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">(9)<br>section<br></span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 1.5%; border: solid; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;Sun</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 1.5%; border: solid; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;Mon</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 1.5%; border: solid; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;Tue</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 1.5%; border: solid; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;Wed</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 1.5%; border: solid; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;Thur</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 1.5%; border: solid; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;Fri</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 1.5%; border: solid; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;Sat</span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 1.5%; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 1.5%; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 1.5%; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 1.5%; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 1.5%; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 1.5%; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 1.5%; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7" style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"><br></span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 3.7763%; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">Tot</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 3.7763%; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">Tot<br></span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 3.7763%; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">Tot<br></span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 3.7763%; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">Tot</span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="21" style="width: 289.333px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" style="width: 289.333px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"><br></span></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="width: 70px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="width: 289.333px; border: solid; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 7px; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 70px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="width: 3.7763%; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="width: 3.7763%; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="width: 3.7763%; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="width: 3.7763%; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" rowspan="4" style="text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 7px; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 70px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
</p>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" style="width: 289.333px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;"><br></span></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="width: 70px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="width: 289.333px; border: solid; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 7px; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 70px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="width: 3.7763%; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="width: 3.7763%; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="width: 3.7763%; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="width: 3.7763%; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" rowspan="4" style="text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 7px; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 269px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 70px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-size: 11px;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&nbsp;</span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center; border: solid;"><span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean, _“loosing the format”_?

Comment: hi @CBroe, the spacing and the size of each <td>. I am using a 3rd party tool to generate a report. I have header section and detail section. In detail section need to follow the same spacing format which is not happening.

Comment: Here you appear to have specified most of the column widths explicitly, so you can try if `table-layout:fixed` gives you the desired result. But in general, the layout of the columns of a table depends on the content of the _whole_ table - so you can not just rip one table apart into two, and expect that to still result in the same automatic column widths across both.

Comment: Hi @CBroe thanks for your reply. I will try this code in my html and will update your. I have added the current output which i am getting in the question.

Comment: Hi @CBroe thanks for your comment. Your code worked for me. Now I am having formatting issue. section 4 and 8.